# Drawing an arc between two known angles

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm way in over my head but too far in to give up now! 
I'm making an app that measures angles to make slope/gradient maps. To get maximum data from minimum reference I need to work out height changes between two angles (Assuming an smooth arc)

The bit that is really stumping me is it has to be between the know $X$ Distance..
I know I'm terrible at explaining.. but here's a highly scientific drawing to help...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbH1D.jpg

I know $X$, $θ_a$ and $θ_b$. but want to know $Y_a, Y_b, Y_c$...

Any guidance would be huge!

Comment: You can almost only guess - but the best guess might be a cubic interpolation ... -- Wait, you only know the *slopes*, but not the *heights* at the two ends?

Comment: Correct. This will be used to find the height differences between the two points. (And hopefully n number of points in between)

Comment: Unless you have a better model for your class of functions, this cannot be done. And this is part of why I have a general rule: if you cannot do something by hand (or imagine doing it by hand, given lots of time and lots of sheets of paper), then you're not ready to write a program to do it, either. That's only based on a half-century of experience, but ...

Comment: Are the things labelled $y_a, y_b, y_c$ the heights at points what are $1/4$, $1/2$, and $3/4$ of the way along the $x$-axis?

Comment: Yes, they dream is that you could have that be any number of samples that you wanted (and computationally possible) for a higher resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up working out what I was trying to explain..

If it was anything like what I actually did explain, well. You tell me..

Here is an example. I ended up having to make an few different iterations for different combinations of angles.

But here is the basics for anyone who has this same problem... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s9susy2ikh

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$
h_(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{\sin(\pi (x))}{\pi x} & x \ne 0\\
1 & x = 0\end{cases}$$

Then $h(0) = 1$, and $h(n) = 0$ for every integer $n \ne 0$. If we let $k(x) = h(x)^2$, then we have $k(0) = 1$ and $k(n) = 0$ for all integers $n \ne 0$, *and* $k'(n) = 0$ for all integers $n$.

With that in mind, let's take a particular example of your data, namely $X = 4$, so that $y_a, y_b, y_c$ are at $x$-locations $x = 1, 2, 3$. Let's also take $\theta_a = \theta_b = 0$. And to further restrict things, let's that $y_a = y_b = y_c = 0$. You might hope that in this case, there's a unique answer for the height-change over the interval. I'll show that this is not true:

The function $u_d(x) = dk(x-4)$ has the following properties:
\begin{align}
u_d'(0) &= \theta_a = 0 \\
 u_d'(4) &= \theta_b = 0 \\
u_d(0) &= 0\\
u_d(1) &= y_a = 0\\
u_d(2) & = y_b = 0\\
u_d(3) &= y_c = 0.
\end{align}

But $u_d(4) = d$, which can be chosen arbitrarily.

Hence finding the $y$-value at the last point of the interval cannot be done from the given data, even in the simplest case -- the problem is simply underdetermined.

Indeed, if all you're given is $X$, $\theta_a$, and $\theta_b$, then my argument shows that $y_a = y_b = y_c = 0$ and $u(4) = $ *anything* is a possible solution.

The function $u$ is amazingly nice -- it's completely smooth, has an everywhere convergent Taylor series, bounded Fourier transform ... it's about as nice a function as you can possibly find. So it's not some weird, degenerate monster that I've cooked up.